# Hibernate stalling freezing when trying to run two identical update statements at the same time: doesn't throw exception or error, just does nothing

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql, deadlock

The two updates could or could not have identical data as well (if this is important please let me know).

I have found that deadlocking is pretty common but ususally an exception is thrown and here nothing happens for a while until the connections expire. What are the most common causes of deadlocking with hibernate and what should be my course of action? I have noticed that the freeze happens for update and not select statements (idk about insert), and I know the problem doesn't have to do with connection pooling.

I am using spring 4.2.5, Hibernate 5.1.0.Final, c3p0 0.9.5.2, and postgresql 9.4.

If you need anything else please let me know, and I would be grateful for any help because I can't find anything online, since in the examples online, a deadlock exception is thrown.

Also I am guessing its a deadlock but I have no idea what it really is.

```
      [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 1143785 [http-nio-8080-exec-30] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections  - Collection found: [com.thebrandsapp.pojo.Product.bellPlatformCategories#193], was: [com.thebrandsapp.pojo.Product.bellPlatformCategories#193] (uninitialized)
    [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 1143785 [http-nio-8080-exec-30] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections  - Collection found: [com.thebrandsapp.pojo.Product.configurableFields#193], was: [com.thebrandsapp.pojo.Product.configurableFields#193] (uninitialized)
    [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 1143785 [http-nio-8080-exec-30] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections  - Collection found: [com.thebrandsapp.pojo.Product.descriptionFields#193], was: [com.thebrandsapp.pojo.Product.descriptionFields#193] (uninitialized)
    [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 1143785 [http-nio-8080-exec-30] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections  - Collection found: [com.thebrandsapp.pojo.Product.productColorImages#193], was: [com.thebrandsapp.pojo.Product.productColorImages#193] (uninitialized)
    [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 1143785 [http-nio-8080-exec-30] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections  - Collection found: [com.thebrandsapp.pojo.Product.productLists#193], was: [com.thebrandsapp.pojo.Product.productLists#193] (uninitialized)
    [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 1143785 [http-nio-8080-exec-30] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections  - Collection found: [com.thebrandsapp.pojo.Product.productPictures#193], was: [com.thebrandsapp.pojo.Product.productPictures#193] (uninitialized)
    [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 1143785 [http-nio-8080-exec-30] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections  - Collection found: [com.thebrandsapp.pojo.Product.productShopifyOption1Values#193], was: [com.thebrandsapp.pojo.Product.productShopifyOption1Values#193] (initialized)
    [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 1143785 [http-nio-8080-exec-30] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections  - Collection found: [com.thebrandsapp.pojo.Product.productVariants#193], was: [com.thebrandsapp.pojo.Product.productVariants#193] (uninitialized)
    [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 1143785 [http-nio-8080-exec-30] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections  - Collection found: [com.thebrandsapp.pojo.ProductVariant.collectionProducts#1731], was: [com.thebrandsapp.pojo.ProductVariant.collectionProducts#1731] (uninitialized)
    [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 1143785 [http-nio-8080-exec-30] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections  - Collection found: [com.thebrandsapp.pojo.ProductVariant.orderPieces#1731], was: [com.thebrandsapp.pojo.ProductVariant.orderPieces#1731] (uninitialized)
    [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 1143785 [http-nio-8080-exec-30] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections  - Collection found: [com.thebrandsapp.pojo.ProductVariant.productPictures#1731], was: [com.thebrandsapp.pojo.ProductVariant.productPictures#1731] (uninitialized)
    [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 1143785 [http-nio-8080-exec-30] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections  - Collection found: [com.thebrandsapp.pojo.ProductVariant.reviews#1731], was: [com.thebrandsapp.pojo.ProductVariant.reviews#1731] (uninitialized)
    [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 1143785 [http-nio-8080-exec-30] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections  - Collection dereferenced: [com.thebrandsapp.pojo.Product.productShopifyOption2Values#193]
    [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 1143785 [http-nio-8080-exec-30] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections  - Collection dereferenced: [com.thebrandsapp.pojo.Product.productShopifyOption3Values#193]
    [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 1143785 [http-nio-8080-exec-30] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener  - Flushed: 0 insertions, 2 updates, 0 deletions to 5 objects
    [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 1143785 [http-nio-8080-exec-30] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener  - Flushed: 0 (re)creations, 0 updates, 2 removals to 21 collections
    [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 1143785 [http-nio-8080-exec-30] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter  - Listing entities:
    [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 1143786 [http-nio-8080-exec-30] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter  - com.thebrandsapp.pojo.ProductVariant{isPermanentlyInactive=false, regularPrice=0.00, dimensionUnit=null, stockQuantity=0, metaDescription=null, taxStatus=null, createdAt=Tue May 24 22:06:02 CDT 2016, inactive=false, reviews=<uninitialized>, inStock=false, id=1731, grams=0, sku=, barcode=, brand=com.thebrandsapp.pojo.Brand#60, brandProductVariantPosition=1, height=0.0, updatedAt=Tue May 24 22:12:11 CDT 2016, taxable=true, upc=null, weight=0.0, brandProductVariantId=21556778823, shortDescription=null, version=12, oldInventoryQuantity=0, requiresShipping=true, name=M, backOrdered=false, permalink=null, shippingClass=null, weightUnit=lb, purchaseable=false, orderPieces=<uninitialized>, inventoryPolicy=deny, collectionProducts=<uninitialized>, description=null, shippingClassId=0, metaKeywords=null, taxClassId=0, option3=null, fulfillmentService=manual, onSale=false, option1=M, option2=null, randomIntToKnowIfStale=9964169, shippingTaxable=false, compareAtPrice=null, taxClass=null, product=com.thebrandsapp.pojo.Product#193, availabilityDescription=null, salePrice=null, backordersAllowed=false, length=0.0, productVariantItemPriceType=null, orderQuantityMaximum=0, orderQuantityMinimum=0, width=0.0, productPictures=<uninitialized>}
    [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 1143786 [http-nio-8080-exec-30] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter  - com.thebrandsapp.pojo.Brand{ppNameFont=null, addresses=<uninitialized>, productListPriceFontSize=0, ppDescriptionHeaderColorHexString=null, plCellBorderWidth=null, ppDescriptionBodyFont=null, productPageTextFont=null, productPageHeaderFontSize=0, productPageSubheaderFont=null, productPageHeaderFont=null, shippingPolicies=<uninitialized>, id=60, plNameFont=null, plBackgroundColorHexString=null, productListTileBackgroundHex=null, brandStripeAccount=null, plLogoBackgroundTopColorHextString=null, version=20, productPageTextFontSize=0, productUsers=<uninitialized>, bellPlatformCategories=[], logoImage=null, ppDescriptionHeaderFont=null, ppNameFontSize=0, name=null, plBackgorundGradientTopColorHextString=null, legalBusinessName=null, ppDescriptionHeaderFontSize=0, productListPriceFont=null, plCellCornerRadius=0, brandStoreSetting=component[accessToken,accessTokenSecret,email,isInstalled,nonce,password,storeHash,storeName,userId,username]{password=null, isInstalled=true, storeName=the-main-main-main.myshopify.com, accessToken=afa83706ed66fcea805a92b6e20a7040, storeHash=null, nonce=1111, userId=null, accessTokenSecret=null, email=null, username=null}, isVerified=false, plCellBorderColor=0, ppPriceBackgroundColorHexString=null, plPriceFontSize=0, plBorderColorHexString=null, plFlowlayoutType=0, productListBackgroundImage=null, products=<uninitialized>, plCellBackgroundColorHexString=null, ppDescriptionBodyColorHexString=null, ppPriceFontSize=0, sellerUserAccounts=<uninitialized>, plCustomized=0, ppPriceFontColorHexString=null, ppNameFontColorHexString=null, productListNameFontSize=0, plNameFontColorHexString=null, productListNameFont=null, referralPercentage=0.0, ecommercePlatform=0, ppDescriptionBodyFontSize=0, brandOrders=<uninitialized>, plBackgorundGradientBottomColorHextString=null, productPageBackgroundColorHex=null, hasSignedUp=false, productPageSubheaderFontSize=0, plLogoBackgorundBottomColorHextString=null, ppPriceFont=null
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 1143786 [http-nio-8080-exec-30] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter  - com.thebrandsapp.pojo.Product{descriptionFields=<uninitialized>, productShopifyOption1Values=[com.thebrandsapp.pojo.ProductShopifyOptionValue#769, com.thebrandsapp.pojo.ProductShopifyOptionValue#770], productListPictureURL=null, isPermanentlyInactive=false, description=, brandProductType=, productLists=<uninitialized>, createdAt=Tue May 24 16:40:09 CDT 2016, inventoryWarningLevel=0, inactive=false, productShopifyOption3Values=null, productVariants=<uninitialized>, id=193, productShopifyOption1=component[name,position]{name=Size, position=1}, sku=null, brand=com.thebrandsapp.pojo.Brand#60, randomIntToKnowIfStale=9964169, productShopifyOption3=null, productShopifyOption2=null, updatedAt=Tue May 24 22:12:11 CDT 2016, productColorImages=<uninitialized>, productShopifyOption2Values=null, availabilityDescription=null, ecommercePlatform=null, upc=null, version=23, productBrandProductId=6776062663, tags=, bellPlatformCategories=<uninitialized>, configurableFields=<uninitialized>, name=tshirt, inventoryLevel=0, productPictures=<uninitialized>}
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 1143786 [http-nio-8080-exec-30] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter  - com.thebrandsapp.pojo.ProductShopifyOptionValue{product2=null, product1=com.thebrandsapp.pojo.Product#193, id=769, value=M, product3=null}
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 1143786 [http-nio-8080-exec-30] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter  - com.thebrandsapp.pojo.ProductShopifyOptionValue{product2=null, product1=com.thebrandsapp.pojo.Product#193, id=770, value=L, product3=null}
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 1143786 [http-nio-8080-exec-30] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue  - Changes must be flushed to space: "BellDatabaseSchema".product_variant
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 1143786 [http-nio-8080-exec-30] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL  - update "BellDatabaseSchema".product set product_availability_description=?, product_brand_id=?, product_brand_product_type=?, product_brand_product_created_at=?, product_description=?, product_ecommerce_platform=?, product_inactive=?, product_inventory_level=?, product_inventory_warning_level=?, product_is_permanently_inactive=?, product_name=?, product_brand_product_id=?, product_list_picture_URL=?, productshopifyoption1_name=?, productshopifyoption1_position=?, productshopifyoption2_name=?, productshopifyoption2_position=?, productshopifyoption3_name=?, productshopifyoption3_position=?, product_random_int_to_know_if_stale=?, product_sku=?, product_tags=?, product_upc=?, product_brand_product_updated_at=?, product_optlock=? where product_id=? and product_optlock=?
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Hibernate: update "BellDatabaseSchema".product set product_availability_description=?, product_brand_id=?, product_brand_product_type=?, product_brand_product_created_at=?, product_description=?, product_ecommerce_platform=?, product_inactive=?, product_inventory_level=?, product_inventory_warning_level=?, product_is_permanently_inactive=?, product_name=?, product_brand_product_id=?, product_list_picture_URL=?, productshopifyoption1_name=?, productshopifyoption1_position=?, productshopifyoption2_name=?, productshopifyoption2_position=?, productshopifyoption3_name=?, productshopifyoption3_position=?, product_random_int_to_know_if_stale=?, product_sku=?, product_tags=?, product_upc=?, product_brand_product_updated_at=?, product_optlock=? where product_id=? and product_optlock=?}
```

Comment: Look in the database: The database will tell you which deadlocks occurred and often give you the clue on where you have to look in your code.

Comment: @Christopher Bell  Exactly what is freezing ?

Comment: @Arul The main thread. I have noticed that if I restart Tomcat, the problem goes away, at least for the first try.